# Screen flickers with Nvidia GPU

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, display, monitor, flicker

When I install the Nvidia driver (have tried both current and post-release current) the monitor flickers every time I open a new window/program such as Firefox. I don't know what else I'm going to do?

Please help because with this flickering I am afraid that my monitor is going to stop sometime.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try using the nouveux graphics driver.
2. If that doesn't work, use Ubuntu 2D when you login (press the Ubuntu logo to the right of your name).
3. If that doesn't work, use the command 'sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop' in Terminal and relog into Lubuntu, it is even more lightweight than Unity 2D so it may not flicker your screen.

(I have added this nVidia driver bug to Launchpad (bug reporting) for you:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/nvidia-drivers-ubuntu/+bug/245383)